# With IPFS, can a developer give complete control of a storage account to a smart contract?

Tags: storage, ipfs, trust

With IPFS, can a developer give complete control of a storage account (or ownership?) to a smart contract?

So that no human can edit/delete the files uploaded by the smart contract to the IPFS network nor upload files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is still not possible as IPFS do not support smart contracts. IPFS is only decentralized data storage solution
Hope Swarm (based on Ethereum) resolves this when it is live.